# How to send Data with jQuery to Django view and render the Django template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have some data in javascript and want to send it to a Django view function. After that I want to render a Django template using HttpResponse, but how it works?

First I had send some data to a Django view with jQuery.ajax() and used the response data, now I want to send data within a second jQuery.ajax() - after a button was clicked - to a different Django view function and finally render a simple template, like how it works, if I click a simple link on a website.

**I have cut the snippet as far as possible for the sake of clarity**

```
$(matchfield).on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var field = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/view-function/",
        data: { "field": field },
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.message === 1) {
                points = 100
                $('#submit').on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/another-view/",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {"points": points},
                        success:function(response){ // I guess the mistake is here
                            $(document).html(response) 
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If the `#submit` Button was clicked, The status code of the Response is 200 and Chrome Dev Tools shows the complete expected new html page in Preview(without css style), but nothing happens on the current page.

This is the Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        // head stuff
    </head>
    <body>
       // Some stuff
    </body>
</html>
```

I used `return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))`

My View-Function:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def another-view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get("points"):
            points = int(request.POST.get("points"))
            template = loader.get_template('my_template.html')
            context = {'message': "any message"}
            return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

This is how my view function works, points are stored in Database and some magic happens, but all works fine and the Request Status Code is 200.

I have unfortunately no idea what I've overlooked.

**The Response from AJAX ( the inner ajax() with url: "/another-view/") is the expected HTML Page, but nothin happens on the current Page. I would like to replace the complete page**

Comment: Show us the Python code for the view function.

Comment: Could you show your views? From your current question, it seems like you don't really need ajax at all.

Comment: Well, from a quick look, you're checking for when the `points` AJAX query is run, but not the `field` one. Do you have `if request.POST.get("field"):` anywhere? (Sorry, prematurely hit submit)

Comment: I suspect it, too, because I just want to pass a variable.@Sam

Comment: @Sam 's 2. Comment: Yes, this is the first view which handles the outer AJAX. My Problem is to get rendered my working second view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to the problem. To redirect to a Django view function with POST data you can use the jQuery.redirect function which is usable after include the jquery.redirect.js from https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect

**USAGE:**

```
/**
* jQuery Redirect
* @param {string} url - Url of the redirection
* @param {Object} values - (optional) An object with the data to send. If not present will look for values as QueryString in the target url.
* @param {string} method - (optional) The HTTP verb can be GET or POST (defaults to POST)
* @param {string} target - (optional) The target of the form. If you set "_blank" will open the url in a new window.
* @param {boolean} traditional - (optional) This provides the same function as jquery's ajax function. The brackets are omitted on the field name if its an array.  This allows arrays to work with MVC.net among others.
* @param {boolean} redirectTop - (optional) If its called from a iframe, force to navigate the top window. 
*/
$.redirect(url, [values, [method, [target, [traditional, [redirectTop]]]]])
```